# using performSegueWithIdentifier() adds an apostrophe to the identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I want to jump from one viewController to another. I have been using `performSegueWithIdentifier` and it works for all viewControllers expect for one. Every time the app tried to perform the segue it prints this error:

> 2016-08-21 15:04:29.170 onboarding[44226:2490189] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'gogo''

My identifier in the segue is "gogo". Also in my code I use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gogo", sender: self)
```

If you look closely at the error message, I noticed that Xcode adds an apostrophe to the identifier. Is prints 'gogo'' instead of 'gogo'. Why is this happening?

Comment: try xcode → product → clean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all it doesn't add another '. Look closer at this part:

```
reason: 'Receiver (<onboarding.QuestionnarieVC: 0x7fa919874a00>) has no segue with identifier 'gogo''
```

The extra ' is from 'Receiver .... '

Are you sure you have set the proper segue ID to the right segue like so:

[image]

Comment: Yes I did set the segue with the correct identifier in the storyboard as well on my code. Still I get the error. I will double check one more time and remake the segue and clean the project, but I have already done it. Thanks for pointing that the apostrophe is from --> ' Receiver. That was driving me nuts.